# resample pandas dataframe at to arbitrary number

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, resampling

I have a loop in which a new data frame is populated with values during each step. The number of rows in the new dataframe is different for each step in the loop. At the end of the loop, I want to compare the dataframes and in order to do so, they all need to be the same length. Is there a way I can resample the dataframe at each step to an arbitrary number (eg. 5618) of rows?

Comment: can you add any code so that we can understand the problem clearly?

Comment: You can resample each numeric row by `np.interp` function and construct new dataframe back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe is too small by N rows, then you can randomly sample N rows with replacement and add the rows on to the end of your original dataframe. If your dataframe is too big, then sample the desired number from the original dataframe .

```
if len(df) <5618:
    df1 = df.sample(n=5618-len(df),replace=True)
    df = pd.concat([df,df1])
if len(df) > 5618:
    df = df.sample(n=5618)
```